# jQuery get data returns undefined in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, undefined

There is a problem in IE 9 returning `undefined` instead of data, when making an ajax request. It works on Firefox, Chrome, Opera. I tried to set some headers in get.php. But it didn't help.

My code is below:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $.ajax({
               type : "GET",
                url : "get.php",
               data : "id=1234&lang=en",
           dataType : 'html', 
            success : function( msg ) {
                         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg);
                     }
           });
       });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: That js works: http://jsfiddle.net/ytNcM/. The problem probably lies in your php. Visit the page with your browser and see what shows up.

Comment: @Asad change you jsfiddle code so that someone who visits that link does not open a dialog box. Now it opened up and cannot be closed.

Comment: @x4f4r It seems to close when I press the close button.

Comment: There is no close button visible on mac for google chrome

Comment: That's get.php contents http://jsfiddle.net/ytNcM/1/ .Are there any requirements to page that returns data ?

Answer (score 2):

Returning the MIMEType of `application/json; charset=utf8` caused this same behavior for me in IE8. Changing it to `application/json;` made IE8 magically start functioning. Check what your server is returning for a MIMEType and see if fiddling with that is causing an issue.

Edit: Actually what was causing the real problem is that it should be `charset=utf-8` and not as shown above without the hyphen.